# Ezra Bridger's Jacket Logo

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

Is there any information regarding the logo on Ezra's jacket?

[image]

[image]

Comment: An homage to [Skywalker sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYml.gif)?

Comment: A stylised [Loth cat](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Loth-cat)?

Comment: A [(hidden) Rebel Starbird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddkvm.png)?

Comment: @Valorum - We've already seen proto-Rebel starbirds in the show and they appear to be unrelated to Ezra but come from Sabine, who was already tagging anything that would stand still with it - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starbird

Comment: Good catch on the Skywalker Sound connection though @Valorum - I'd certainly like an in-universe answer but that's close enough to justify an out of universe connection answer - https://hegeekshegeek.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/star-wars-rebels-ezra-skywalker-sound1.png?w=700

Comment: Looks like a womp rat.  I used to bullseye them in my T-16 back home.

Comment: @NKCampbell - That's a fair point and you're right, it's worthy of putting into an answer even if it doesn't cover the "in-universe" bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's certainly a more than passing similarity between the logo on Ezra's jacket and the company that does the sound production on Star Wars: Rebels, [Skywalker Sound](http://www.skysound.com/).

**Ezra Logo** vs. **Skywalker Sound Logo**

[image] [image]

Nor would this be the first time that this logo has been sneaked into a Star Wars property.

[image]
<sub><sup>Star Wars: Attack of the Clones - Speeder scene</sup></sub>

Comment: Skywalker Sound was created out of the group that did sound for Star Wars.  Just as ILM was the effects group.  Both companies are part of Lusasfilm.  At this point it would be more shocking to see animation not done by Lucasfilm animation, sound not done by Skywalker Sound, or effects not done by Industrial Light and Magic, than to note that any Star Wars property uses them.  You can almost take it for granted.

Comment: @Xalorous - Well indeed.

Comment: The Skywalker Sound idea is definitely smart and probably true, but there would have to be an in-universe explanation. My theory is that Sabine took inspiration from Ezra's jacket to create the Starbird. This would make sense since they were very close and Sabine often took inspiration from the Ghost crew. What was the logo before Sabine thought about it? My guess is that it has something to do with the planet of Lothal, since it has a very "Loth" look to it.

Comment: @SnipsTano - Probably a [Loth-cat](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Loth-cat)

Comment: @SnipsTano - except that, as Valorum states in a previous comment above, Sabine was already using the starbird prior to meeting Ezra, certainly prior to becoming very close to him.